# Fix IE display linked img / footer nav

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i'm having a hard time getting my Footer Navigation to show up properly now that I'm using some new CSS rules. In addition to this problem IE 9 shows my IMG with a border around the outside of it (much like the underline of a linked item).

Questions as follows:

1. Why is IE creating a border despite img a { text-decoration: none; } ?
2. What is up with the footer being all wonky? What am i missing?

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/misterizzo/fTe5Q/

```
<

body>
<div id="bg">
   <img style="display:block;" src="http://cdn-ci53.actonsoftware.com/acton/attachment/8908/f-0015/1/-/-/-/-/Background_Gradient.png">
</div>
<div id="main">
 <div id="header">
  <div id="top-left"><a href="http://medata.com/"><img src="http://cdn-ci53.actonsoftware.com/acton/attachment/8908/f-0019/1/-/-/-/-/Medata%20With%20Sub%20550x131.png" alt="Visit Medata Home Page" class="logo" title="Medata.com" atl="Logo"></a>
  </div>

    <div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://newsworthy.medata.com/" target="_blank"><span class="button">NewsWorthy</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="button">Solutions</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="button">About Us</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="button">Home</a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

<div class="acton">
{{TEXT}}
</div>

<div id="footer">
<ul>
        <li><a href="http://newsworthy.medata.com/" target="_blank"><span class="button">NewsWorthy</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="button">Solutions</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="button">About Us</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="button">Home</a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>



</div>
</body>
```

Everything shows up nice in current FF and Chrome browser (as usual)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question:

You should use a normalise.css to make browsers behave more consistent. 
http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

This is the bit you need out of that file.

/**
 * Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 8/9.
 */

```
img {
    border: 0;
}
```

Second question:

Try to increase the width of your footer ul

```
#footer ul {
   width: 530px;
}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: "a img {...}", not "img {...}", you only need to remove the border if inside an a tag, not always

Comment: Well, both will work! This is how browsers handle img tags, so why no reseting it globally for all browsers?

Comment: if he puts that style at the end of the css, maybe he resets some border he actually wants, 'a img' is safer, but yeah, both will work

Comment: Thanks both of you! I"ll try this on Tuesday when i get back into the office!